# How to add java_opt to wildfly in openshift?

Tags: java, openshift, wildfly

I want to add JAVA_OPTS setting to the standalone configuration for wildfly in openshift. 
What is the best way to do this?

Do i need to do this by an action hook? Is this action hook also invoked when the server is restarted using "ctl_app restart"?

Or is there another way the add JAVA_OPT settings?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the JAVA_OPTS_EXT environment variable to set any extra JAVA_OPTS that you would like your application to use.

Try using this command to set it:

```
rhc env-set JAVA_OPTS_EXT=VALUE
```

Comment: What is best way to set this property? I tried using a pre_start action hook, but it didn't work.

Comment: Isn't it possible to configure this in a file?

Comment: Why is this property not picked up when you set it in a pre_start action hook? Is there a different way in handling these properties?

Answer (score 0):

The file to add them to is:  .openshift/action_hooks/pre_start_wildfly
export JAVA_OPTS_EXT=VALUE